# Does apt fix the clock during an update?

Tags: apt

I have a Raspbian with `tor` installed which I updated using `apt`, with the `apt update` and `apt upgrade` commands run through `torify`. All the other services (including ntp) except for `tor` were stopped so that `tor` was the only service running at the time. The clock was manually set to a different time from the local time but correct enought for `tor` to be able to establish a connection and get node information.

After `apt` downloaded the updates and in the middle of applying them, I noticed that clock had updated itself to the correct local time.
Since `tor` usually complains when the clock is set outside of a certain range and does not connect until the clock is reset to the correct time, I assume `tor` is not responsible for this.

Is this something `apt` is able to do during update?

Comment: Was `ntp` upgraded during the update?

Comment: Looks like it was not.

Comment: If you stop ntp doesn't systemd-timectl take over again?